# Please Review Whether Moderation Appropriately Flagged Question As "Off-Topic" Or Whether Flag Was Politically Motivated

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Physics Stack Exchange post: [Does Thermal Radiation From A Colder Object Get Absorbed By A Hotter Object?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/808364/does-thermal-radiation-from-a-colder-object-get-absorbed-by-a-hotter-object)

I have very little faith in the moderation of this site, and have already asked about this unaware of the meta forum. Therefore, I will not add further comments regarding the science of the original question. See the original post and moderator's note within it. Please let me know whether the question itself genuinely falls outside the purview of "mainstream physics" as a "pet theory" or whether it is merely a question seeking clarification about how physics works (that may possibly be politically inconvenient for certain positions).

Just one other question in light of this. Do physicists and this site's moderator team have a professional obligation derived from ethics to censor discussion on the basis of activism to "save the planet"? Or, does science itself require open discussion to prevent the influence of politics and money on scientific consensus?

The answer to this question would seem to settle the original question about the nature of moderator behavior here.

Now that I have found the meta forum, this is my final post on the topic unless moderation policy changes.

Comment: Pertaining to the scientific content: the question I asked references the phenomenon of scattering: "temporary absorption followed almost immediately by re-emission without change in wavelength". Most respondents to this topic will argue that blackbodies absorb all radiation which hits them, ignoring what mechanisms cause scattering. Thus the meta topic is whether questions about scattering constitute non-mainstream physics in contrast to representing the ignoring of scattering as "mainstream physics".

Comment: If your question is actually about whether a blackbody scatters radiation, it would have been worded so, and my latest comment on your post also covers that. Your political rant clearly relegated that to a fringe problem, which is why nobody thought it was the focus of your issues. Blackbody radiation is an un-missable and unmistakeable part of mainstream physics.

Comment: … no moderator was involved in comments or closure….

Comment: In 24 hours, you've described users of this site as "shills," "dunces," "conformists," "oblique," bastardizers and adulterants of science, "politically oriented," "unscientific," and "scoundrels." It sounds like you're having a very bad time here—unless this is how you get your entertainment. I think the moderators have been far too kind in not showing you the door.

Answer (score 9):

So first, I know that facts get in the way of good stories but let's agree that no moderator was involved in the closure or comments of your question ont the main site (at least at the time of this writing).

Next, this site is NOT one where questions of the type "please peer-review my theory" are accepted.  You can rant about this, but this is basically what your question is as per your:

> I would specifically like for answers to address the flaws or merits in the reasoning I present...

If you want to debate your personal theory or challenge the scientific consensus, then do so *elsewhere* as the site is dedicated to mainstream physics only.